# Problem with the underscore '_' caracter with natbib and footnotebackref package?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am having a problem with the underscore with LaTeX + `natbib` + `footnotebackref`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{footnotebackref} %%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, urlcolor= blue, linkcolor= blue, citecolor=blue, } %%%
\begin{document}
hello \citep{Potter1994}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

and the bib file:

```
@article{Potter1994,
abstract = {deleted for short},
author = {Potter, Ma and Jong, Ka De},
doi = {10.1007/3-540-58484-6{\_}269},
file = {:home/me/ppsn94.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {3-540-58484-6},
journal = {Parallel Problem Solving from Nature},
pages = {249 -- 257},
title = {{A cooperative coevolutionary approach to function       optimization}},
url = {http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-58484-6{\_}269},
year = {1994}
}
```

It works properly when I remove the two lines marked with `%%%` but I'd like to keep coloring links, URLs and citations.[image: Here is what I get like this]

Any solutions?
Thank you

Comment: The `doi` and `url` fields should be the literal data, not escaped for typesetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I see two big missunderstandings here.

First you used command `\hypersetup` without loading package `hyperref`.  In the documentation of `hyperref` (`texdoc hyperref` on your console/terminal) you can read that `\hypersetup` is used to set options for package `hyperref`.

The second is that with field `url` in your bib file and loaded `hyperref` (that implicit loads package `url`) you have not to mask an underscore with `\`.

Please try the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Potter1994,
  abstract = {deleted for short},
  author   = {Potter, Ma and Jong, Ka De},
  doi      = {10.1007/3-540-58484-6_269},
  file     = {:home/me/ppsn94.pdf:pdf},
  isbn     = {3-540-58484-6},
  journal  = {Parallel Problem Solving from Nature},
  pages    = {249--257},
  title    = {{A cooperative coevolutionary approach to function optimization}},
  url      = {http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-58484-6_269},
  year     = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{footnotebackref} %%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true, 
  breaklinks=true, 
  urlcolor=blue, 
  linkcolor=blue, 
  citecolor=blue, 
} %%%

\begin{document}
hello \citep{Potter1994}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

and see the result:

[image]

Comment: Your ***MWE*** works perfectly. I _unescaped_ the Latex special characters form my bib file and it worked. Actually, I was using `hyperref` until a problem with footnotes not working forced me to leave it and to use `footnotebackref`. Thank you.

Comment: In case anybody else like me runs into more or less the same problem, but with amsrefs instead of bibtex, a very similar command solves it (and turns the DOI into a hyperlink): `\renewcommand{\PrintDOI}[1]{DOI \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}`